# How to make Spring ignore @RequestMapping annotations in specific packages

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I've been playing around with the concept outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284911/can-a-spring-cloud-feign-client-share-interface-with-an-spring-web-controller/32463376#32463376) answer, to share a common 'contract' between server and client. I'm trying to use this concept in a Spring MVC application that contains both REST endpoints and a Feign client. The `@RequestMapping`s on the REST endpoints are picked up like normal by Spring, but: it also picks up the `@RequestMapping` on the abstract API class I use for my Feign client, i.e., in terms of the linked example, I have a `UserService` and `UserClient` in my code, and Spring picks up the `@RequestMapping` in the `UserService` class.

I don't understand why this happens in the first place, because:

- The `UserService` class is an interface. Why and how does Spring think it can map an endpoint to an interface method?? This will obviously never work.
- The package containing `UserService` is *not* included in the `basePackage` list of the `@ComponentScan` annotation on my `Application` class

Any clues on how I can convince Spring to just ignore all classes in this package??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this is a known issue, see [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/466) thread for ways to fix it.